# How do I modularize javascript files in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, module, export

I previously did not import functions into scripts in my chrome extensions, but I ran into a problem when redeclaring the function when I ran the script multiple times. However, now I am unable to import functions. I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at content-script.js:1:1)`

How could I workaround the function declaration problem or ideally how do I import functions within a chrome extension?

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "homepage_url": "url",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "title",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at" : "document_idle",
      "js": ["modules.js", "content-script.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://website.com",
        "http://website.com"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://website.com",
    "https://website.com"
  ]
}
```

and this is my content-script.js file that gets run on a button click:

```
import { checkQuestion } from "./modules.js";
console.log("script working");
checkQuestion();
```

and finally, this is my modules.js file:

```
const someFunction = () => {
    // do stuff
};

export { checkQuestion };
```

Comment: Simply remove `import` and `export` lines entirely and it'll work.

Comment: This does not fix the problem, I now get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: checkQuestion is not defined

Comment: Since it works when done correctly, you probably did something wrong e.g. your example shows someFunction being declared and not checkQuestion. Another reason may be that the function/const is not global. Debug your code.